# Hoverable dropdowns menu example in W3

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used the example of w3

```html
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
```

and then I tried to put div into center horizontally.

I tried a lot such as 
    { margin: 0 auto } 
but nothing changed...

Is there any way to center ?

Thanks

Comment: to center div just give it a width and margin:auto it will work

Comment: add a fiddle preview is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to center a certain element using margin: 0 auto, you should define both **width** and **display:block**

```
.centercontent{
     width: 500px;
     display:block; 
     margin: 0 auto;
  }
```